# Start Library module activity

Tags: android

I have a library module and Main module and I try to start the `activity` that is defined in library module from other android application. I tried many ways but I didn't succeed. I tried to...

1. set Component name
2. set class name
3. class for Name

Also, I declared activity tag in my manifest.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you added your library module as dependency in main module?

Comment: Have you added library module as dependency in main module?

Comment: yes i added library module dependency by  implementation project ()

Comment: if you don't know, please tell me about start service from other application in same case.